# how to speed up pandas df.apply (probably with np.where or np_logical_and.reduce?)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm looking to speed up the generation of a new column inside a pandas dataframe, with the code of myFunc() to be executed per each row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["EMA4","EMA4prior","EMA10","MACD"])

    def myFunc (self, row):
           if ((row.EMA4 > row.EMA10) and (row.EMA4prior < row.EMA10) and (row.MACD > 0)):
            return 0
           if ((row.EMA4 < row.EMA10) and (row.EMA4prior > row.EMA10) and (row.MACD < 0)):
            return 1
        return -1

self.df["position"] = self.df.apply(self.myFunc, axis=1) #apply this per each row
```

The code works, but it is painfully slow. I have tried the following approaches to improve it, but something in the syntax seems wrong:

**1.- using numpy.where directly:**

```
a=self.df["EMA4"].values
b=self.df["EMA4prior"].values
c=self.df["EMA10"].values
d=self.df["MACD"].values
self.df["position"] = np.where(((a > c)&(b < c)&(e > 0)),0, 
                       (np.where((a < c)&(b > c)&(d < 0)), 1, -1))
```

**2.- Using np.logical_and.reduce** , because it seems that np.logical_and is binary operator (and I have 3 "and" to calculate):

```
self.df["position"] = np.where(np.logical_and.reduce([(a > c),(b < c),(e > 0)]),0,
                        (np.where(np.logical_and.reduce[(a < c),(b > c),(e < 0)]), 1, -1))
```

I'm not getting it to work, it doesn't compile and I'm not sure what's wrong.

So, is there any way to speed up the original myFunc() with numpy or some other way to improve performance?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you should be able to use `np.select`:

```
cond = [(df.EMA4 > df.EMA10) & (df.EMA4prior < df.EMA10) & (df.MACD > 0), 
        (df.EMA4 < df.EMA10) & (df.EMA4prior > df.EMA10) & (df.MACD < 0)]
result = [0,1]

df['position'] = np.select(cond, result, -1)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Cool.  I am glad I could help.

Comment: Could be possible to improve the condition in this simple case?: `cond = [(self.df.MA1 >= self.df.MA2 ), (self.df.MA1 < self.df.MA2 )]`. I mean, it seems strange having to calculate both statements, because the first imply the second.

Comment: Look ar np.where in this case it acts more like an if statement.

Comment: Oh, of course, you're right, thanks! So, for the records, it would be like this: `df["position"] = np.where (self.df.MA1 > self.df.MA2,1,0)`